# How to make Cross Domain Request to an API from Javascript Client when I don't have access to modify the other domain API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, crossdomain-request.js

I have a scenario where I need to fetch JSON response data from an API in a different domain. Lets say the requesting domain is ClientDomain and the API domain in APIDomain.

Now I know that this can be achieved using **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header in the API server and then using a client ajax marking the CrossDomain attribute as true, etc.

All my search leads either to modify the API settings to add the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header or do a proxy coding in backend server code. But in my case, I don't have access to the API code and I can't change anything there. I'm able to do a proxy read from C# controller code and fetch data from the APIDomain. I want to know how this can be achieved only with Javascript/Jquery in my current scenario.

**Edit:** Is there a way to do proxy-ing via Javascript/Jquery?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Make an API/page on ClientDomain and access it via Javascript/Jquery. In that API/page call the API on APIDomain and return its data.